# Does giving manual radius to a shape makes it look bad?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, logo, graphic-styles

Basically, I'm confused between geometric/mathematics and aesthetic point of view. I need a shape as shown in image for my logo. Now, in the 2nd half of image, you see two objects. **One** has inner radius and **other** has none.

I made the first by the process illustrated in first half of following image:

a) Drew a circle with side length **120** px

b) Increased the stroke width to **60** px and made it contain inside of path

c) Gave border radius of **60** px

c) Distorted the one end of shape to see the stroke properly and finally expanded it and removed unwanted part

Now, it seems right to me according to Illustrator's own handling but it doesn't look cool to me at least. So I was thinking to **give it inner radius manually**.

One way to achieve both inner and outer radius was to give stroke width less than 60 px, but that I don't want. I need exactly half.

Is the little manual radius (inside curvature) here in the 2nd shape makes it more weird or makes it better? In other words, which of the 2 will most designers prefer over other?

[image]

Comment: This really all boils down to *opinion*. I voted to close as such. There are no rules I'm aware of regarding this. It's left to the aesthetic eye of the designer.

Comment: By the way which one do you think looks better? With inner radius 0 or with 0+?

Comment: I agree with @Scott, to talk in terms of what "looks better" is purely subjective.

Comment: @BillyKerr I didn't understand what you mean by "subjective". Could you please give a little idea about it?

Comment: It means it's based only on opinion, not facts.  Such questions are generally off-topic here, unless you can amend the question to follow the [critique guidelines](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/682/89608), it'll probably get put on hold.

Comment: Hi @BillyKerr  I've edited the title and detail. Please check it now.

Comment: All you did was change *how* you are asking for opinion - the words you use. But you are still merely asking for an *opinion*. There are no rules here.. if it looks good to you, then use it.

Comment: Maybe. But does it mean I can't ask something like this here? If I could, how would I ask? In the guidelines, I saw you can ask something like "Is there enough white space in the logo so it's easily identifiable?" which is also opinion based?

Comment: Ask yourself why you need someone else to tell you if the rounding looks good or not. Don't you know if it does? It's your logo. If someone disagrees with you and tells you *not* to use any rounding... and you *hate* the way it looks in your logo. Are you going to design a logo for yourself you hate?

Comment: Not really :P But I like the rounded one more. Okay I'd follow your advice. But one last thing: Geometry also matters in graphics designing. For example think about popular logos like Google. I don't think they just made it in such a way that it looks good. I guess they used some calculations. So how do I distinguish when to use "natural" things and when to use "looks good to me"? That's all for what I wanted to know this thing.

Comment: Geometry is important when that is what is being conveyed. But quite honestly the *ultimate* deciding factor is exactly "what looks good", geometric or not. There are cases, such as the Google logo, where if the geometry is incorrect it *doesn't* look good. So.... it's not a a one-size-fits-all thing. It's **art** not *mathematics*, one has to be aware of when to break the rules and when not to. (Odd that so many questions lately seem to what formulas for the creation of art... that's not what art is.)